# Load Event of Iframe in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have the iframe below:

```
<iframe id="frameID" name="myframe"> </iframe>
```

On the same page, I have a form:

```
<form id="formID" action=".." target="myframe">
    ...
</form>
```

The form is submitted by JQuery:

```
$('#formID').submit();
$('#frameID').one('load', function (){
    alert(...);
}
```

The problem is that alert didn't show up in firefox. What I am missing on this? Is the code above also works for Internet Explorer?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. iframe.load(...) runs in chrome and IE, but not firefox.. 'Course i'm on jQuery v1.3.2 - which i'm pretty sure is incredibly out of date

Comment: Also seems to be a problem in v1.6.4 and v 1.8.3

Comment: Seems my problems are related to the iframe loading too quickly in firefox, and jQuery.load does not fire its callback if the iframe loaded before the callback was bound.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but this may help others looking here for an answer.

I think I just had the same problem. I see you have "action" instead of "src", and you say you posted a form, which is exactly what I did.

The problem I had was I was uploading an image to an IFRAME - my upload mechanism returned a blank page with no content. In this case FireFox does not seem to fire the load event.

I fixed it by returning "OK", then the load event starts firing.